# Query on class B private address range

Tags: ip, ipv4

This is the range for class B private address range.

`172.16.0.0 - 176.31.255.255`

prefix notation for this is `172.16.0.0/12`

As per prefix notation, 8 bits of left most octet and left most 4 bits in second octet can only be used to derive network ID in the IP address.

So, I can derive network address using x in  xxxxxxxx.xxxx0000.00000000.00000000

*My question:*

Using leftmost 12 bits, How can i derive 172.17.0.0 and 172.18.0.0 network address? In general, How can i derive `172.16-172.31` range using left most 12 bits(mentioned as x)?

Comment: Forget that about "Class B". This notation is obsolete. Only the /12 is relevant...

Comment: i think you mean CIDR subnetting

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear about what you ask: the notation /12 leads to the net mask

```
11111111.11110000.00000000.00000000
NNNNNNNN.NNNNHHHH.HHHHHHHH.HHHHHHHH (network part / host part)
```

which can be combined with `172.16.0.0`:

```
10101100.0001HHHH.HHHHHHHH.HHHHHHHH (H = host part)
```

This means that every IPv4 address which starts with these 12 bits belongs to this network.

This counts for all IPv4 addresses whose first octet is 172 and second one is between 16 (00010000) and 31 (00011111).

And this range includes 172.17.* and 172.18.* as well.

What we have talked about here is how the network part of the address forms. Inside one network, each host gets assigned an address, making use of the host part.

These addresses can essentially be freely assigned (except that the host part may not be all 0s or all 1s).

How you use/divide up your 172.16/12 is up to you.

You can see 172.16/12 see as one big network where all hosts are in, but you can as wee split it up even further:

- maybe into 172.16/13 and 172.24/13
- or into 172.16/14, 172.20/14, 172.24/14 and 172.28/14
- or into 172.16/15, 172.18/15, 172.20/15, 172.22/15, 172.24/15, 172.26/15, 172.28/15 and 172.30/15
- or into 172.16/16, 172.17/16, 172.18/16, ..., 172.29/16, 172.30/16 and 172.31/16
- ...

You can even mix that: you can as well have e. g. 172.16/13, 172.24/14 and 172.28/14.

Commenting on your comment:

> can i say that as per prefix notation /12, the possible networks here are 172.00010000.0.0, 172.00100000.0.0, 172.00110000.0.0, 172.01000000.0.0, 172.01010000.0.0 , 172.01100000.0.0, 172.01110000.0.0 etc...

No. As said, 172.16/12 means 172 is constant and the first bits of 16 are constant.

As mentioned, that means 10101100.0001... is fix and the rest is variable.

Comment: but prefix 12 says that you can't use last 4 bits in second octet, right? for network ID, you only need to use first 4 bits in second octet, Is my understanding correct? so how did we use this 31 (00011111)?

Comment: For 31, you are using host bits 0001_1111_ but /12 prefix notation says you can modify only left most 12 bits.Did you understand my question?

Comment: here octet of question is given in binary notation, can i say that  as per prefix notation /12, the possible networks here are 172.00010000.0.0, 172.00100000.0.0, 172.00110000.0.0, 172.01000000.0.0, 172.01010000.0.0 , 172.01100000.0.0, 172.01110000.0.0  etc... so these are first 2 network addresses, so where is 172.17.0.0 and 172.18.0.0?

Comment: @overexchange The prefix notation tells where the boundary between network part and host part is. And /12 means that all 8 bits of the first octet and the *upper* 4 bits of the second octet belong to the host part.

Comment: @overexchange "but /12 prefix notation says you can modify only left most 12 bits." Opposite: you *cannot* modify these bits, i. e. use them for host addressing. They are constant.